# How to get the tax amount in the thank you page in magento

Tags: magento, checkout, subtotal

I am trying to get the tax amount to deduct from the total amount or just get the bare subtotal amount so i can put it in an affiliate link but I am not being able to get the tax amount or bare subtotal in the last thank you page after the customer clicks the place order button. I tried:

```
 <?php echo $_product->getData('tax_amount'); ?>
```

and

```
  $totalItemsInCart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount(); //total items in cart
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
$subtotal = round($totals["subtotal"]->getValue()); //Subtotal value
$grandtotal = round($totals["grand_total"]->getValue()); //Grandtotal value


if(isset($totals['tax']) && $totals['tax']->getValue()) {
    $tax = round($totals['tax']->getValue()); //Tax value if present
} else {
    $tax = '';
}

echo $tax;
```

but with no luck; I could not get the tax amount I could just get the subtotal with the tax amount.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount')
```

Here you will get your tax amount

Comment: I only get null ... I am pretty sure that the 'thank you page' / success page magento converts quotes into orders and closes the quote so no surprise, this might work in the checkout though.. but not what I was after..